# Tic-tac-toe error. str object integer

Tags: python

```
def new_board():
    """Create new game board."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board
```

Error:

`TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

I am programming in Python and I am trying to program a tic-tac-toe program. What do I do?

Comment: What's `NUM_SQUARES`?

Comment: Strange, I ran your code and I didn't get that error. (if you're thinking, "Oh, that's not my _whole_ code, I just shared the part I thought would be relevant", please share your whole code because it is all relevant.)

Comment: The code sample is very unclear. You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide code that lets us know what the the values are so that we can help you.

Comment: We don't need or even want to see all your code (regardless of @Kevin's comment), just a minimal amount that's runnable and reproduces the problem. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please explain what a __tic-tac-toe program__ is, or refer to an explanation

Comment: I just realized a problem. Sorry for wasting your time